# RSA PSS security advantage

Tags: rsa, signature, rsa-pss

To my humble opinion, please correct me if I'm wrong, RSA-PSS (PKCS#1 ver 2.1) advantage over RSA as described in PKCS#1 ver. 1.5 is in its security proofs. Does this proof and the advantage is still there even if the "salt" in the RSA-PSS scheme is constant over all messages, or it conditioned in generating a random salt each and every signature? That is, does the security proof of RSA-PSS assumes random salt over messages?

Comment: Related to [Why use randomness in digital signature algorithms?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25182/555).

Answer (score 4):

Even if we make [`RSASSA-PSS`](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=27) deterministic by fixing its seed, it remains with a security proof in the Random Oracle Model per Full Domain Hashing (Jean-Sébastien Coron, [*On the Exact Security of Full Domain Hashing*](https://www.crypto-uni.lu/jscoron/publications/fdh.pdf), in [proceedings of Crypto 2000)](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-44598-6_14). We can't say the same for [`RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5`](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=31), because a lot of the message representative is fixed.

In practice, a better argument to use deterministic `RSASSA-PSS` rather than `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` is that vulnerable implementations of verification of `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` abound, when I know no vulnerable implementation of `RSASSA-PSS` verification (regardless of randomization), and this is less likely to happen accidentally.

However a practical argument against `RSASSA-PSS` is that it requires careful specification of the hash *and* the mask generation function: even if the later is almost universally MGF1, that could be with another hash (e.g. stuck to SHA-1) depending on implementations.

Comment: Could you give an example on how RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 is vulnerable and an example? Or should I ask this in a separate question?

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 as specified has no known vulnerability. Some incorrect implementations of its signature verification step are vulnerable. Example among dozens: [CVE-2014-9934](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-9934). For something more detailed, a questions seems in order, but I do not know if it is for crypto.se or security.se.

Comment: Yeah, if you skip validating the padding in its entirety then it may be vulnerable :P The incompetence of some people in the field is just astonishing. Goodness gracious. Thanks anyway. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: It could be easy to use XOF instead of MFG1, isn't it?

Comment: @kelalaka: in theory, XOF can be used instead of MGF1; see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/37769/555). In practice, modifying existing code, library, and test vectors is work. And that can only be done with new applications.